# Python - to output contents in a HTML file to spreadsheet

Tags: python

Part of below is sourced from another example. It’s modified a bit and use to read a HTML file, and output the contents into a spreadsheet.

As it’s a just a local file, using Selenium is maybe an over-kill, but I just want to learn through this example.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import lxml.html as LH
import lxml.html.clean as clean
import xlwt

book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8', style_compression = 0)
sheet = book.add_sheet('SeaWeb', cell_overwrite_ok = True)

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
ignore_tags=('script','noscript','style')

results = []

driver.get("source_file.html")
content = driver.page_source
cleaner = clean.Cleaner()
content = cleaner.clean_html(content)
doc = LH.fromstring(content)

for elt in doc.iterdescendants():
    if elt.tag in ignore_tags: continue
    text = elt.text or ''                                 #question 1
    tail = elt.tail or ''                                 #question 1
    words = ''.join((text,tail)).strip()
    if words:                                   # extra question
        words = words.encode('utf-8')                     #question 2
        results.append(words)                             #question 3
        results.append('; ')                              #question 3

sheet.write (0, 0, results)

book.save("C:\\ source_output.xls")
```

1. The lines `text=elt.text or ''` and `tail=elt.tail or ''` – why both `.text` and `.tail` have texts? And why the `or ''` part is important here?
2. The texts in the HTML file contains special characters like `°` (temperature degrees) – the `.encode('utf-8')` doesn’t make it a perfect output, neither in IDLE or Excel spreadsheet. What’s the alternative?
3. Is it possible to join the output into a string, instead of a list? Now to append it into a list, I have to `.append` it twice to have the texts and `;` added.

Comment: For question 2 what do you expect to be a perfect output?

Comment: thanks, sk11. the output in Excel is "Â°", and on IDLE is "\xc3\x82\xc2\xb0", however I want it pure as it shows on HTML as "°".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elt` is a html node. It contains certain `attributes` and a `text` section. `lxml` provides way to extract all the attributes and text, by using `.text` or `.tail` depending where the text is.

```
<a attribute1='abc'> 
    some text     ----> .text gets this
    <p attributeP='def'> </p>
    some tail     ---> .tail gets this 
</a>
```

The idea behind the `or ''`is that if there is no text/tail found in the current html node, it returns `None`. And later when we want to concatenate/append `None` type it will complain. So to avoid any future error, if the text/tail is `None` then use an empty string `''`

---

Degree character is a one-character unicode string, but when you do a `.encode('utf-8')` it becomes 2-byte utf-8 byte string. This 2-byte is nothing but `Â°` or `\xc3\x82\xc2\xb0`. So basically you do not have to do any encoding for `°` character and Python interpreter correctly interprets the encoding. If not, provide the correct shebang on top of your python script. Check the [PEP-0263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

---

Yes you can also join the output in string, just use `+` as there is no `append` for string types for e.g.

```
results = ''
results = results + 'whatever you want to join'
```

You can keep the list and combine your 2 lines:

```
results.append(words + '; ')
```

Note: Just now i checked the `xlwt` documentation and `sheet.write()` accept only strings. So basically you cannot pass `results`, a list type.

Comment: Thanks, sk11. Glad to see you again. Not the first time you are helping me. Great! Thanks for the help on question 1 and question 3.

Comment: Question 2: 005° is displayed as "005\xc3\x82\xc2\xb0"; and if I don't do "encode('utf-8')", it gives "u"005\xc2\xb0". And it still writes to Excel as “Â°”.

Comment: An extra question: what’s the role of “if words:  ” there? Thanks.

Comment: To check if `words` is not an empty string

Comment: Glad it helped you. 
If the degree symbol is still giving troubles then use `encode('cp1252')` with the degree symbol. For e.g. `words = u'005°'   words = words.encode('cp1252')`. Hopefully excel understands this encoding :-)

Comment: Great, so it works? If yes, I will update the answer rather than having this important info in the comments section :)

Comment: yes, it writes to Excel nicely, only IDLE displays odd character.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example for Q1

```
from lxml import etree
test = etree.XML("<main>placeholder</main>")
print test.text #prints placeholder
print test.tail #prints None
print test.tail or ''  #prints empty string

test.text = "texter"
print etree.tostring(test) #prints <main>texter</main>

test.tail = "tailer"
print etree.tostring(test) #prints <main>texter</main>tailer
```